# Is there something better than libnotify?

Tags: linux, perl, libnotify

I'm trying to write some code against libnotify, but the documentation for perl with libnotify is *seriously* lacking. So is there something that, as of 2011-08-26, is "better" than libnotify? All I need is to send a notification to the currently logged in user on a Linux machine (Ubuntu specifically).

Comment: where is there a perl interface to libinotify? do you have a link?

Comment: Also is the user at a terminal or x session?

Comment: @Joel [Gtk2::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-Notify) is what provides the connection to libinotify. And the user will be at an X session.

Comment: ok now I sound ignorant (though by definition I am as I have never used `libinotify`) but are libnotify and libinotify the same? From what I see libinotify is about monitoring file changes, not user notification.

Comment: @Joel I'm a moron. I've been working with `libinotify` recently as well, and managed to type that in instead of libnotify. Luckily, it seems everyone else worked around my stupidity :) I've modified my question accordingly.

Comment: @gsm8994, no problem. Being unfamiliar with either, I was having a hard time understanding what was going on.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/174885/how-to-write-to-kdes-osd-or-notification-from-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Gtk2::Notify`](http://p3rl.org/Gtk2%3a%3aNotify) does seem to lack good documentation, but you can browse through some examples at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/FLORA/Gtk2-Notify-0.05/examples/ including the basic one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk2::Notify -init, 'Basic';

my $n = Gtk2::Notify->new('Summary', 'This is some sample content');
$n->show;
```

In fact this seems pretty cool, I may use it for something soon! Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Otherwise:

On Linux you can use `zenity` to send a popup message, and to send it to another user's screen you have to play with some environment variables but it can be done. From Perl I would set the appropriate `%ENV` values and then just execute `system` or backtick (``) calls to `zenity`.

Perhaps start here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/spice-up-your-unix-linux-shell-scripts.html

Also from within that link, perhaps `libnotify-bin`/`notify-send` would also work, depending on the message you are sending.

```
perl -E '$ENV{DISPLAY} = ":0.0";`notify-send "Hello World"`;'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I searched, when porting an application from Windows to Linux, there's no :(

I'll glad to here if there's.

**Update**: Indeed I was talking about libinotify and not about libnotify.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell freedesktop specification contains a notification service which can be accessed via dbus.
Here is a link to a [perl module](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SACAVILIA/Desktop-Notify-0.03/lib/Desktop/Notify.pm) for that feature.